# Wordpress, Link is not working in the php file

Tags: php, wordpress

```
<div class="grid col-300 fit">
        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( 'http://www.oilgassearch.com/contacts' ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Contacts' ); ?>">  Contacts</a><a href="<?php echo esc_url( '' ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( '|' ); ?>">
                |</a><a href="<?php echo esc_url( 'http://www.oilgassearch.com/privacy-policy' ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Privacy' ); ?>">
                Privacy</a><a href="<?php echo esc_url( '' ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( '|' ); ?>">
                |</a>
<a href="<?php echo esc_url( 'http://www.oilgassearch.com/recruitment-fraud-warning' ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Fraud alert' ); ?>">
            Fraud alert</a> </div>
```

Contacts and Privacy is working but fraud is getting override.What should I do?

Comment: How is it getting overriden?

Comment: thats what  i  am trying to figure out.Contact and Privacy is working fine but for fraud is not working